# Row Selection in Enhanced Grid

Tags: dojo, grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am new to Dojo and i came across a problem that has me completely stumped. I am creating a data grid in Dojo with the Enhanced Grid .

Each row in the grid has a checkbox with which the row can be selected. The checkbox has been implemented using the  indirectselection plugin.

Now when i select a row using the checkbox everything works fine. But when I select a row by clicking on other data cells the row does'nt get selected !

Heres the JSP part of the datagrid

```
<table  data-dojo-id="grid" data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" plugins="{indirectSelection: {headerSelector:true}, filter: true,pagination: true}"
    data-dojo-props="store:icGrid, 
     clientSort:true "  formatterScope="myFormatters" 
    style="width: 100%; height: 20em;">
     <thead>
         <tr>
      <th width="25%" field="empNo"  formatter="formatLink">empNo</th>
      <th width="25%" field="name">name</th>
      <th width="25%" field="email">email</th>
      <th width="25%" field="phone">phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

If I remove the code referring to indirect selection (plugins="{indirectselection...) the rows get selected when I click on other data cells (as they should). But I also need the checkbox that the indirectselection implements.

Is there a way to make the indirectselection work without taking away the row select functionality ?

Take a look at the grid in the page I will link below. I need a grid that works like that
(The last grid in the page with the checkboxes)

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/working_grid/demo/selector.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by 1. using the cellClick event to listen 2. Get the rowindex of the cell when it is clicked 3. set it to selected.

```
grid.on("CellClick", function(event)
    { 
        var rowId = event.rowIndex;
        grid.selection.setSelected(rowId, true);
        grid.render();
          }
```

grid.selection.getSelected(); did not return the selected rows and I am wondering if this is a compatibility issue ? It seems like when i use the indirectSelection plugin the row Select is behaving in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard about DGRID . 
I think you should check it. 
It really works very good with dojo .

Here are some useful sites .

[Dgrid Main webpage](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/)

[Git hub Documentation](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid)

Comment: Yes . It seems like my team decided not to use DGrid for some reason. So I am looking for a fix which works with the existing EnhancedGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below to listen to grid selection and check what `selectedRows` return and use the index of that row to toggleRow

```
dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", function(e) {
     var selectedRows= grid.selection.getSelected();
     grid.rowSelectCell.toggleRow(selectedRows[i], true);
});
```

Comment: grid.selection.getSelected did not return the selected rows !. I was not able to figure out why. But i managed to resolve the issue by using the CellClick event and getting the 'event.rowIndex' and setting it to selected.

Answer (score 0):

Simple code :- "SelectionChanged"` even is available. so code like this:-

```
grid.on("SelectionChanged", function(event)
    { 
        var rowId = event.rowIndex;
        grid.selection.setSelected(rowId, true);
        grid.render();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The "SelectionChanged"` even is available. so code like this:-

```
grid.on("SelectionChanged", function(event)
    { 
        var rowId = event.rowIndex;
        grid.selection.setSelected(rowId, true);
        grid.render();
    }
```