# DOJO indirect selection to be checked when row data gets changed

Tags: dojo

I have a dojo editable datagrid with indirect selection plug-in. Now my requirement to select the check box of indirect select when user changes the data in row . Please help me how i can achive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it by the event onRowClick. If a user clicks into one cell, then the event fires.
Here's the reference : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox

And this SO-Thread seems to solve your Problem: [Row Selection in Enhanced Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438185/row-selection-in-enhanced-grid)

Regards